# how to get and return response variable and use it in other places from node.js request api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest

I am currently new to node.js and I actually implementing chat system in my ongoing project , frontend is angular and using node.js for socket functionality.

Right now I am stuck with one issue that I am not getting desired value while returning in function which calls external api using "request" in node.js. I am calling same function in socket on event and want record id for my purpose.

Below is code for calling external api which is located on php server from node.js.

```
const insertChatData = (body) => {
            const url = adminUrl + 'chatSystem';
            let recordId;
            request.post({
                url,
                headers,
                body,
                json:true } , (error , res) => {
                    recordId = res.body.recordId // getting value here correctly 
                }
            )
            console.log(recordId , 'boo') // getting undefined here  
            return recordId // returned undefined
        }
```

Below is the code for socket event where I am trying to call the required fuction in order to get record id and I want emit back that to my client which is angular .

```
socket.on("sendingMessage2", (msgData, hsocId) => {
   //some coding stuff....
   let recordId = insertChatData(msgData) // gtting undefined

   });


 Please let me know what is the correct approch in order to get and return the recordId back to calling socket event. Thanks.
```

Comment: use one of the usual asynchronous coding patterns - callbacks,or the easier to use callbacks called Promises, or the easier to use Promises called async/await

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs is asynchronous because of which it is undefined. The console is executed before the API call. To make it work you can use async-await to make your code look synchronous.

```
const insertChatData = async (body) => {
      const url = adminUrl + 'chatSystem';
      const response = await request.post({
            url,
            headers,
            body,
            json:true })
      const recordId = response.data.recordId;
      console.log(recordId , 'boo') 
      return recordId 
}

socket.on("sendingMessage2", async(msgData, hsocId) => {
   //some coding stuff....
   let recordId = await insertChatData(msgData) 
});
```

Comment: Assumes `request.post` returns a Promise of course